# Matlab parallel programming

Tags: multithreading, matlab, image-processing, parallel-processing

First of all, sorry for the general title and, probably, for the general question.

I'm facing a dilemma, I always worked in c++ and right now I'm trying to do something very similar to one of my previous projects, which is to parallelize a single-target object tracker written in matlab in order to assign to each concurrent thread an object and then gather the results at each frame. In c++, I used boost thread API to do so, and with good results. Is it possibile in matlab? Reading around I'm finding it rather unclear, I'm reading a lot about the `parfor` loop but that's pretty much it? Can I impose synchronization barriers similar to `boost::barrier` in order to stop each thread after each frame and wait for other before going to the next frame?

Basically, I wish to initialize some common data structures and then launch a few parallel instances of the tracker, which shares some data and take different objects to track as input. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `parfor` is restrictive but does allow huge speed improvements, if you play by its rules.

Sometimes calling multiple single matlab instances from the command line can give you more control.

Comment: As far as I know, one requirement of `parfor` is the strict independence of the processes running. So what you ask depends upon the way you think you'll arrange your processes scheduling.

Comment: The fact is that I need to run the different instances simultaneously, possibly displaying results after each frame, which inherently requires some sort of synchronization between the multiple instances. I'm starting to think that this can't be done in matlab, is it correct? The various instances have nothing in common except for some read-only variables (if it is a problem I can always make a copy of those, but I think I have bigger issues right now)

Comment: @powder, I'd suggest to state more clearly the effects you are willing to obtain in the question.
I guess properly rearranging the loops something can be done, nonetheless it's quite likely you won't be able to reach c++ performance (not even by far.)

Answer (score 4):

`parfor` is only one piece of functionality provided by Parallel Computing Toolbox. It's the simplest, and most people find it the most immediately useful, which is probably why most of the resources your research has found discuss only that.

`parfor` gives you a way to very simply parallelize "embarassingly parallel" tasks, in other words tasks that are independent and do not require any communication between them (such as, for example, parameter sweeps or Monte Carlo analyses).

It sounds like that's not what you need. From your question, I'm not entirely sure exactly what you do need; but since you mention synchronization, barriers, and waiting for one task to finish before another moves forward, I would suggest you take a look at features of Parallel Computing Toolbox such as `labSend`, `labReceive`, `labBarrier`, and `spmd`, that allow you to implement a more message-passing style of parallelization. There is plenty more functionality in the toolbox than just `parfor`.

Also - don't be afraid to ask MathWorks for advice on this, there are several (free) recorded webinars and tutorials on this sort of parallelization that they can point you towards.

Hope that helps!